# Hyperledger fabric: Peers in in same organization trying to use wrong address to setup chaincodeListenAddress

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have hyperledger fabric setup that should deploy one organization with multiple peers as a docker swarm. When trying to deploy peer containers, every peer but the first one will discover the first peer's address when auto detecting peer address. Due to this each new peer tries to set up with the first peer's address and shut down.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml setup for peer0:

```
peer0:
hostname: peer0.org0.example.com
image: registry.gitlab.com/myregistry/peer:staging-0.6.0-3
privileged: true
deploy:
  mode: replicated
  replicas: 1
  restart_policy:
    condition: on-failure
  update_config:
    parallelism: 1
    delay: 60s
networks:
  my_network:
    aliases:
      - peer0.org0.example.com
ports:
  - 7001:7051
  - 7003:7053
volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock
    - /opt/myproject/config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    - /opt/myproject/client0/config.json:/etc/hyperledger/ext_config/config.json
    - /opt/myproject/crypto-config:/etc/hyperledger/ext_config/crypto-config
    - /var/local/peer0_persistent_data:/var/hyperledger/production
    - /opt/myproject/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org0.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
    - /opt/myproject/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org0.example.com/peers/peer0.org0.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
environment:
  - COUCHDB_ADDRESS=peer0_couchdb:5984
  - COUCHDB_USER=fabric
  - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=fabric
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org0.example.com:7051
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=my_network
  - GODEBUG=netdns=go
  - GRPC_GO_LOG_VERBOSITY_LEVEL=99
  - GRPC_GO_LOG_SEVERITY_LEVEL=info
  - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=DEBUG
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
```

And peer1:

```
peer1:
hostname: peer1.org0.example.com
image: registry.gitlab.com/myregistry/peer:staging-0.6.0-3
privileged: true
deploy:
  mode: replicated
  replicas: 1
  restart_policy:
    condition: on-failure
  update_config:
    parallelism: 1
    delay: 60s
networks:
  my_network:
    aliases:
      - peer1.org0.example.com
ports:
  - 7011:7051
  - 7013:7053
volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock
    - /opt/myproject/config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    - /opt/myproject/client0/config.json:/etc/hyperledger/ext_config/config.json
    - /opt/myproject/crypto-config:/etc/hyperledger/ext_config/crypto-config
    - /var/local/peer1_persistent_data:/var/hyperledger/production
    - /opt/myproject/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org0.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
    - /opt/myproject/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org0.example.com/peers/peer1.org0.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
environment:
  - COUCHDB_ADDRESS=peer1_couchdb:5984
  - COUCHDB_USER=fabric
  - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=fabric
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=my_network
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org0.example.com:7051
  - GODEBUG=netdns=go
  - GRPC_GO_LOG_VERBOSITY_LEVEL=99
  - GRPC_GO_LOG_SEVERITY_LEVEL=info
  - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=DEBUG
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
```

With this setup peer1 gives me the following error:

```
2019-09-18 10:22:24.838 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 013 Auto-detected peer address: 10.255.168.52:7051
2019-09-18 10:22:24.838 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 014 Returning peer0.org0.example.com:7051
2019-09-18 10:22:24.839 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 015 Auto-detected peer address: 10.255.168.52:7051
2019-09-18 10:22:24.839 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 016 Returning peer0.org0.example.com:7051
2019-09-18 10:22:24.842 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 017 Entering computeChaincodeEndpoint with peerHostname: peer0.org0.example.com
2019-09-18 10:22:24.843 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 018 Exit with ccEndpoint: peer0.org0.example.com:7052
2019-09-18 10:22:24.843 UTC [nodeCmd] createChaincodeServer -> WARN 019 peer.chaincodeListenAddress is not set, using peer0.org0.example.com:7052
2019-09-18 10:22:24.847 UTC [nodeCmd] createChaincodeServer -> ERRO 01a Error creating GRPC server: listen tcp 10.0.51.21:7052: bind: cannot assign requested address
2019-09-18 10:22:24.847 UTC [nodeCmd] startChaincodeServer -> PANI 01b Failed to create chaincode server: listen tcp 10.0.51.21:7052: bind: cannot assign requested address
panic: Failed to create chaincode server: listen tcp 10.0.51.21:7052: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

How can I make peer1 detect it's own address instead of peer0? This problem won't exist with multiple orgs with one peer or with 3org2peers setup that comes with hyperledger caliper, but it isn't deployed as swarm.